# Add class to body before page loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My vue app needs to determine if it is being viewed by desktop or mobile device.

No problem there.

However, there is a "hiccup" when the app looks disproportionate for a second or two on load and that is not acceptable.

How can my vue app alter the body tag immediately so the page loads smoothly?

Thank You

UPDATE:

**Thanks A.Broderick for your help -- my solution below**

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having the initial styling of the app get to `display: none;` Then have a conditional which reacts to whether it is being loaded on desktop or mobile? That way either one will have to be selected first from an inital blank page. However, if it is taking a few seconds to load it seems there may be some issues with how the code is structured, care to post it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Vue Router? If so you can make the calculation of whether it is pc or mobile in the router functionality. Most likely you'll want to put the calculation in a "beforeEach()" function in your router, or if it's just a page or two you could put it in a "beforeRouteEnter()" function on the individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks A.Broderick for your help**

Here's how it works for me:

1. HTML:

   ```
   <html>
     ....
   <style>
     .noDisplay {
       display: none;
     }
   </style>
     </head>
     <body class="noDisplay">
      ....
    </body>
   ```
2. App.vue:

   ```
     <script>
     // 3rd party
     var MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect')

     // Shell
     import DesktopShell from './components/layout/desktop/d_shell.vue'
     import MobileShell from './components/layout/mobile/m_shell.vue'

     export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
        return {
        windowWidth: 0,
        windowHeight: 0,
        goMobile: this.IsMobile()
        }
   },
   components: {
     appDesktopShell: DesktopShell,
     appMobileShell: MobileShell
   },
   methods: {
     IsMobile: function () {
       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
       ) {
         this.goMobile = true;
         document.body.className += ' ' + 'is-mobile';
         document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('noDisplay');
         return true;
       }
       else {
         this.goMobile = false;
         document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('noDisplay');
         return false;
       }
     },
   },
   mounted() {
     this.$nextTick(() => {
       window.addEventListener('load', () => {
         this.windowWidth = window.outerWidth
         this.windowHeight = window.outerHeight
       });
       window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
         this.windowWidth = window.outerWidth
         this.windowHeight = window.outerHeight
       });
     })
   },
   ```

   }

Comment: Mo problem Francis, another tip may be to have the `IsMobile` function on `mounted: {}` instead of methods. That way the function will automatically fire on the app being loaded, see [here for more](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)